# Is it safe to store informations (through variables) in a .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

Is it safe to store informations using `SetEnv` in a `.htaccess` file ?

Thank you

Comment: No, the last guy that tried that poked his eye out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about as safe as storing informations in any other file on a web server. If a malicious user can get a script onto the server, or subvert one that's already there, then retrieving env vars is a trivial exercise.

Comment: But then, how is it safer to store it in a `.php` files or any other files?

Comment: It all depends on the threat models you're defending against.

Comment: If someone manage to read a file on my server, then there is no real way to hide a Database password anywhere right?

Comment: You can hide it, you can obfuscate it, but if someone's got access to the server, it can be found.